# How do I build an on/off switch for my project?

Tags: switches

I'm building a project which is going to have an on/off switch and an emergency off switch.

I understand the whole normally off and normally on thing, but how do I actually build one? Or even just, how do they work? Does the mechanical contact made by the switch have to stay there throughout the usage of the device? I assume it does, so how can I make that?

I want it to go on and off without it switching on one way and then the other. Imagine a push button start switch in a car. And I want to build one, so it matches the design of my project.

Comment: a switch is just two wires touching ... why would you build a switch?... makes more sense to buy one

Comment: all of this info belongs in the question ... it does not belong in the comment ... the question should have clear information about the project, the problem you are trying to solve and a clear question about what you would like to know

Comment: research `momentary contact switches` and research `flip flops`

Comment: You can buy emergency off buttons that latch off until reset if you push them.  They're pretty commonly installed on large machinery, laser systems, etc.  Buying a standard E-stop button for this purpose is a good idea, especially if it is really important that the emergency off work reliably and be really easy to spot in an emergency.

Comment: *I want it to go on and off without it switching on one way and then the other. Imagine a push button start button in a car.* Yeah, you just buy those :) Toggle switches can have stable and momentary positions. Momentary positions are active only as long as you apply force to the lever. Once the force is removed, a spring returns the lever to the neutral position. Building reliable switches is not terribly easy - it's much easier to look around for switches you need instead. Look for *catalogs* by switch manufacturers to learn the terminology. Many of us learned that way!

Answer (score 3):

An electromagnetic relay may be used for on / off control of an electrical device.

[image]

A latching emergency-off push button switch and two momentary push button switches would be required.

When the 'on' push button is momentarily actuated, the relay 'K1' latches and the device is energised.

The device is switched off when the 'off' push button is momentarily actuated.

Actuating the 'emergency off' push button latches it and disables the system till it is released by turning its mushroom head.